# namespace and soap tags in single xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

Input:

```
<user>
  <firstName>John</firstName>
  <lastName>Doe</lastName>   
</user>
```

Output:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.abc.com/v1">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <v1:user>
     <v1:firstName>John</v1:firstName>
     <v1:lastName>Doe</v1:lastName>         
  </v1:user>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm able to achieve this by adding namespaces in one xsl using identity transform and soap tags using another xsl
but not able to do it in single xsl.

Can anyone please help me to achieve in single xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source document belongs to no-namespace, and the rest of the code is static. To simply prefix the elements in your source document, match them (*****) and create copies prefixed with `v1`, applying a namespace with the `namespace` attribute. The XSLT below produces the result you are expecting:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                          xmlns:v1="http://www.abc.com/v1">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
          <xsl:element name="v1:{name()}" namespace="http://www.abc.com/v1">
             <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a template matching `/` that outputs the SOAP elements and does an `apply-templates` inside, then you can add your templates that change the namespace of the input elements.